# How to make multiple variants of an enemy mob scene?

Tags: godot, scene

I'm just starting out in Godot 4. I followed [this](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_2d_game/index.html) tutorial on how to create my first game, and I'd like to add some new features to make it more interesting, and start coding some stuff of my own.

I'd like to create different colour mobs, and have the player's score increase with the number of mobs of the correct colour they collect (the correct colour being defined as the player launches the game). I've recoloured the animated sprites from the tutorial, now I'd need to create a scene for each colour of mob (I'll probably be adding some more stuff depending on the mob's colour later, so I prefer having them distinct rather than choosing a sprite randomly).

To do this, should I extend the current mob scene? Is that something that's possible?

Or should I copy + paste the existing mob scene to have the same starter functions and properties for each one, and then customise the individual scenes after?